# Editing a summary with quote markup

Tags: discussion, editing, formatting

Let me start by saying, this is *not* accusatory.  I honestly don't know the answer, so I'm asking.

I posted an answer to a question, and included a general summary of the article I linked, just in case "link rot" ever sets in.  The question is here:

[Why was there a robot in Rocky IV?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84647/why-was-there-a-robot-in-rocky-iv/84648#84648)

It was edited so that the summary was wrapped in quote markup.

Is this the proper way to handle a user's summary of a source article?  I understand that if it was a direct quote then it's definitely the way to go, but is a summary something that should be wrapped in quote markup?

Again, I'm not asking so that someone will take any action.  I'm just curious for future answers I give.

Comment: By the way, I saw your comment on that answer. If you want to address an editor specifically, you can actually use the `@`-syntax with their user name. It won't autocomplete, but it will give a notification, at least when it's the last editor of the post.

Answer (score 5):

As you thought yourself already, when you're summarizing an article in your own words in contrast to quoting it verbatim, **putting the text in quote markup is not appropriate**, it's not a quote afterall.

This was likely just a mistake on the editor's part but has also been fixed already.